# Can't step into stored procedure on remote SQL Server 2008

Tags: windows, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008, remote-debugging

I have a domain controller installed on virtual `Windows Server 2008 x64`.

`SQL Server 2008 Express x64` is running on `Windows Server 2008 x64` and client on `Windows 7 RTM x86`. Both have joined the domain.

I'm starting both `Visual Studio 2008` and `SQL Server Management Studio 2008` under domain admin user. This account is a member of group `sysadmin` on `SQL Server`.

Server has firewall exceptions for both `TCP` and `UDP` on ports `135-139` and `1433-1434`.

`Visual Studio 2008 Remote Debugger` services is started on server and `Domain Admins` group is allowed to debug.

Remote DCOM works: I can attach to remote server and list it's processes, can switch to show only managed code, etc.

When I'm starting debugging of a query in SMS I'm getting this error:

> Failed to start debugger Error HRESULT
>   E_FAIL has been returned from a call
>   to a COM component. (mscorlib) Program
>   Location:
>
> at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32
>   errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
>
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.DebugSession.DebugCallbacks.OnSqlInitializeDebuggingEvent(ISqlInitializeDebuggingEvent
>   sqlInitializeDebuggingEvent)
>
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.DebugSession.DebugCallbacks.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Interop.IDebugEventCallback2.Event(IDebugEngine2
>   debugEngine, IDebugProcess2
>   debugProcess, IDebugProgram2
>   debugProgram, IDebugThread2
>   debugThread, IDebugEvent2 debugEvent,
>   Guid& riidEvent, UInt32 attribute)

and

> Unable to access the SQL Server
>   debugging interface.  The Visual
>   Studio debugger cannot connect to the
>   remote computer.  A firewall may be
>   preventing communication via DCOM to
>   the remote computer. Please see Help
>   for assistance.

and

> Unable to start program MSSSQL://server.mydomain.local/master/sys/=0

And  when stepping-in into a stored procedure using VS I'm getting the first one and this:

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x89710016

What have I do?

Comment: My post on MSDN got no answer too http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/cc7de769-36ee-4b5d-8a5f-b84ce600ef2b/

Comment: I saw the post by coincidence just a second ago (recognised your avatar) - MSDN has a solution there now, Turn On FileSharing.

Comment: @Jeremy: In post above or some another?

Comment: i'm getting tired of Microsoft's "broken by default" policy.

Comment: @Ian: You're so true, especially in this case

Answer (score 1):

Once I disabled the firewall on both client and server, it worked.

Comment: Yes, but in real world it nearly impossible to disable the firewall on a server, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable remote debugging on the database. You could run the following to do that.

> %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Shared\1033\rdbgsetup.exe

Also, make sure you can connect to the remote SQLServer before you debug, since your logs point to a connection issue.

Comment: I have already installed, started and configured VS 2008 Remote Debugger. How to setup database debugging using it? Connection is being created without problems.

Comment: From visual studio,use server explorer to connect with db and expand stored procedure that you would like to debug and put a breakpoint. When you run the application you will be able to step into & debug the sproc.

Comment: I can't step into a SP from it's context menu in Server Explorer in VS with the same errors